# Xcode doesn't build source files for the framework, creating an unusual product

Tags: ios, xcode, module, frameworks, clang

I'm facing an issue where non-source files are being compiled, resulting in a peculiar framework with an empty headers folder and no binary file.

I'm using CocoaPods to manage my project, which includes a main app and several pods structured as follows:

```
Main WorkSpace
 - App Project
 - MyUIKit Project
 - URLRouter Project
```

The App depends on MyUIKit, and MyUIKit depends on URLRouter. However, when I build the MyUIKit target, the URLRouter target participates in the compilation process in an unexpected manner. The resulting URLRouter.framework has an empty headers folder, and the binary file is missing. The build log indicates that no source code is compiled, and no dependencies are created, and no errors are reported!

Interestingly, when I open the URLRouter project individually, the URLRouter.framework is created successfully, with all source files being built. However, within the main workspace, this behavior is not consistent. Deleting the DerivedData folder does not resolve the issue.

This is occurring in Xcode version 15.2. I'm seeking insights into why this might be happening. Any help would be appreciated.

The following is a snapshot containing both the Build Log and the Product folder:
[image]